# Expo + React Native: What is the "right way" to wrap a 3rd party native library?

Tags: react-native, expo

What is the "right way" to wrap a 3rd party native library (android and ios) and expose it to Javascript in an Expo + React Native project? What is the best route to pursue? Are there any comprehensive examples I should study?

Here are some things I've tried doing to execute simple native code without any 3rd party dependencies involved:

- Vanilla React Native app (npx react-native init AwesomeProject) + Turbo Module = **Success**
- Vanilla Expo app (npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject) + Turbo Module = **Failure**
- Vanilla Expo app (npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject) + Vanilla Expo module (npx create-expo-module AwesomeModule) = **Success**

Since I want to use Expo, the 3rd options seems like a great route for me to take. But now I'm stumped on how to actually pull in the 3rd party library I want to use. For example, in `awesome-module/ios` there is a `AwesomeModule.podspec` file, but no `Podfile` to add a dependency to. Should I add a `Podfile`? Should I add a dependency to AwesomeApp's `Podfile`? Am I taking the wrong approach? Should I re-focus on a React Native Module?

**Resources I've used so far:**

- [Expo Modules API](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/) and related articles in that section.
- Studied the "example" app generated by `npx create-expo-module AwesomeModule`
- [Turbo Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules) and [Prerequisites for Applications](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/new-architecture-app-intro)

Comment: hi, i'm facing the same situation right now. I want to integrate an Android/iOS SDK into my Expo project. I'm using the Expo Native Module strategy but without success. Have you found a proper tutorial or example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `Expo` you have two main workflows - the `managed work-flow` and the `bare work-flow`. See [here](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/) for the documentation on these workflows.

In the past the only option for including 3rd party libraries was to eject your `Expo` project (Which is a one-way operation - no going back) so that it became a standard `React Native` application and then include the 3rd party libraries that you need in your `React Native` project.  The reason for this was that the `managed work-flow` used `Expo Go` on the device to provide the required native functionality and there was no way to add 3rd party libraries to `Expo Go`. So what `Expo` provided is what you could use.

This has subsequently changed, and there now is a way to include 3rd party libraries. You do this by making use of [EAS build](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/) to build your own custom development client (which then replaces Expo Go on your android or iOS device). It took me a while to figure out how all of this works, but the steps in a nutshell are the following:

1. Do an `expo prebuild` to prebuild the `iOS` and `Android` folders. In the `iOS` folder you will then find the `Podfile` that you were looking for. You can make changes that you need to in the `Android` or `iOS` folder and running the `EAS` build will not overwrite the changes that you make here.
2. If you made any changes to the `Podfile` for `iOS`, you need to execute  `npx pod-install` in the iOS folder.
3. Create an EAS account and then use one of the following commands to build your project:

   eas build --profile development --platform android

   eas build --profile development --platform ios

The above commands will start the build on the EAS server, after sitting in a queue for while (the length of the queue depends on the time of day and how busy the server is).

The `iOS` build command will prompt you for your `Apple` account and will guide you through creating and provisioning profiles for your test devices.

If an error occurs during the build, you will have to log into your EAS account and view the logs to see the error message reported.

Once the `EAS` build completes, you will be given a `QR code` which you can then scan on your `Android` or `iOS` device to install your custom development client.

Once the custom development client is installed you can then launch your application, which now includes your 3rd party library, by running the following from your project folder:

```
npx expo start --dev-client
```

You will then be given a `QR code` that you can then scan on your mobile device, and your application will then launch inside your custom development client.

It is also possible to setup your own `Windows` machine to do the `EAS` build for `Android` if you do not want to use the `EAS` server.  If you have a `Macbook` you can set it up to do the `EAS` build for `Android` and `iOS`. A lot of dependencies need to be installed to setup your machine to do an `EAS` build, though. [Here](https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/) is the documentation for setting up you `Windows PC` or `Macbook` to do `EAS` builds. (Note that a `Windows PC` cannot build for `iOS` as `Xcode` is required).

If you want to do the `EAS` build locally, then add `--local` to the `EAS` build commands given above.

Comment: caveat: every time you run `prebuild` changes will be lost